# Populating UITableView from NSArray with indexPath.row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am trying to populate 
`UITableView in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method with an array I have initialized in viewDidLoad method.

```
self.questionsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Q1",@"Q2",@"Q3",@"Q4",@"Q5",@"Q6",@"Q7",@"Q8",@"Q9",@"Q7",@"Q8",@"Q9",@"Q10",@"Q11"];
```

I understand how to implement various sections and reusing a cell with an identifier.  As most of the examples I have seen, I tried like  `question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.  %@", indexPath.row ,[self.questionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

But I am getting like
0. Q1      1. Q2        2. Q3        3. Q4        4. Q5       5. Q6      0. Q1       2. Q2 ....

Please help to load all questions (NSString) to my TableView.  I messing up with indexPath.row.  Its very difficult to understand.  Any tips for best practices to handle indexPath effectively.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return [self.questionsArray count];
        case 1:
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}    
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {           
        static NSString *QuestionCellIdentifier = @"QuestionCellIdentifier";

        UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:QuestionCellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"QuestionCell" owner:self options:nil];
            }
            cell = questionCell; // IBoutlet    
            self.questionCell = nil;              
        }

           question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.  %@", indexPath.row ,[self.questionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        return cell;    
    }       
    else if (indexPath.section == 1){

        static NSString *CustomCellIdentifierMore = @"CustomCellIdentifierMore";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifierMore];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifierMore] autorelease];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            switch (indexPath.row) {

                case 0:
                    cell.textLabel.text=@"Select";
                    break;                

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }   

        return cell;
    } 
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your entire cellForRow implementation. The error is most likely to be there.

Answer (score 1):

cellForRowAtIndexPath is not guaranteed to load cells in order and will be called to update certain cells. You also need to provide the numberOfRowsInSection method, for example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.tableData count];
}
```

Are your cells displaying properly or is it just the nslog that is producing confusing output?

Comment: I returned number of rows with [questionArray count].  Cells are displaying properly.  My problem is I am not able to retrieve array elements from start to end with indexPath.row.  thanks for ur immediate reply.

Comment: Are you using multiple sections or just one?

Comment: multiple sections.. but i have no problem to exactly have desired number of rows in each section

Comment: Ah right, indexPath.row only returns the number of elements in a section. I would use a nested array that holds an array per section then would reference it like this return [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Answer (score 0):

Try calling reloadData on your tableView after creating questionsArray in viewDidLoad, so like this:

```
self.questionsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Q1",@"Q2",@"Q3",@"Q4",@"Q5",@"Q6",@"Q7",@"Q8",@"Q9",@"Q7",@"Q8",@"Q9",@"Q10",@"Q11"];
//or whatever your property for the tableview is called.
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: i am accessing only inside corresponding switch case.. problem for me is not with number of rows.  i am not able to get exact row number inside first section. thanks.

Comment: Please post your entire methods for cellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView

Answer (score 0):

Your cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation is a little funky. First, the curly brackets for indexPath.section == 0 condition don't match. Second, I don't see where you are setting the text for cell that you are returning. Whatever you are assigning to question.text should be assigned to cell.textLabel.text. Third, for indexPath.section == 1 condition, you are only setting the text when the cell is nil. The table view is pretty smart about cell management. When a cell goes out of view due to scrolling, it will reuse the cell instead of entirely creating a new one. So, whenever you deque a cell, it may not always be nil. So, you should be setting the cell text outside the if (cell == nil) loop.